# How can I share a snapper configuration between two OSs in a dual-boot?

Tags: dual-boot, snapper

I followed the instructions [here](https://ramsdenj.com/2016/04/05/using-btrfs-for-easy-backup-and-rollback.html#snapshots) to set up snapshots for a portion of my hard drive – `snapper -c multimedia create-config /home/qwertystop/multimedia`, deleting the `.snapshots` subvolume, recreating it to not be a child of the thing it's snapshotting. That all worked.

Then I set up a dual-boot (original was Mint, new is Arch). I would like the snapshotting to continue regardless of which OS I'm booted into at the moment. I'm not sure how to do this.

I have tried:

- Copying the `/etc/snapper/configs/multimedia` file from one OS's root partition to the other. Snapper on the destination OS does not see the config, according to `snapper list-configs`. Perhaps there's another file somewhere I'm missing?
- Creating the config with the same `create-config` command as I used originally. Snapper reports a failure to create the `.snapshots` subvolume, because it already exists – accurate, but I can't find a way to tell it to use/share the existing one at that location.

I'm not sure what else to try. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Unmount the existing `.snapshots` subvolume, *delete the mountpoint*, create the config, delete the newly-created subvolume, recreate the mountpoint, and remount the old snapshot subvolume. Forgot about deleting the mountpoint.